# Why is backup and restore suffixed with "(Windows 7)" in my Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup

The back up and restore feature in Windows 10 is suffixed with the text "(Windows 7)". Is this just because it's the same system that was available in Windows 7, or does it suggest some specific link / relation to the Windows 7 operating system?

Why is it suffixed like this?

I'm creating a Windows 10 system image - will this work and will I be able to restore from it?

Example:

[image]

Comment: are you happy with my answer for this question? Could you consider accepting it now that you have had time to consider it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows 8 and later the Windows 7 Control Panel applet "Backup and Restore" has been *deprecated* and renamed to "Windows 7 File Recovery" (Windows 8) and "Backup and Restore (Windows 7)" in Windows 10. This means that Microsoft no longer intend to develop it and you can expect that one day they will remove it from future Windows versions.

Meanwhile, it is fully functional although Microsoft do not recommend that you use it in conjunction with their replacement tool which is called File History.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848073(v=vs.85).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Some of the worst names ever used... they think people get to win 10 passing through previous releases, but that is not necessarily the case for everyone.

Answer (score 2):

[How to Use All of Windows 10’s Backup and Recovery Tools](http://www.howtogeek.com/220986/how-to-use-all-of-windows-10%E2%80%99s-backup-and-recovery-tools/), this article will give you good explanation about WIndows 10 backup and Windows 7 backup.

Windows 10 system image only create Window system image, while the apps and other beside Windows are not included.

If you create backup with Windows 7 backup, you can create backup all image from your system including all apps and everything as same as at the state when you create the backup image.

If you collaborate Windows 10 system image with Windows 7 backup, you can repair Windows 10 image and also can restore the computer back to the state when you create the Windows 7 backup.